# CDK Upgrade: cannot find equivalent to "expect(SynthUtils.toCloudFormation(stack)).toMatchSnapshot())"

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I am new to CDK and right now I need to upgrade the CDK version for my code but in the test, the old CDK has the SynthUtils as below

```html
expect(SynthUtils.toCloudFormation(stack)).toMatchSnapshot()
```

I searched a couple of places but cannot find an equivalent for this command. I wonder if someone can help me with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi it's not available in aws-cdk version 2, you can use toJSON instead from the Template class. For code example please refer to official aws cdk github examples. I will paste the specific code snippet that you might need:

https://github.com/cdklabs/aws-cdk-testing-examples/blob/main/typescript/test/processor-stack-snapshot.test.ts

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your snippet!! Let me test it out!